# If/then statements with awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, bioinformatics

I'm trying to solve a bioinformatics problem that is hiding behind an `awk` problem.

I have a tab-delimited file where the first column is either an integer (1-25) OR a string (KN#######). I need to append a few characters to the beginning of the line depending on which it is. Here is what I have so far, but isn't working (i.e. - nothing happens, and no error is being written to STDOUT, which makes me think I'm goofing hard somewhere).

```
awk '{
if ( $1 ~ /^[0-0]+$/ )
'$1="chr"$1'
else 
'$1="chrUn_"$1'
}' someFile
```

example:

```
1 100 100
1 100 100
KN1234 100 100
```

should become

```
chr1 100 100
chr1 100 100 
chrUn_KN1234 100 100
```

Comment: `[0-0]` should probably be `[0-9]`, no?

Comment: Please **edit your Q** some sample input and expected output, given those inputs. Good luck.

Comment: You are also missing a `print` statement after the end of the if-else just before the closing curly brace. And the `$1` reassignment statements should not be surrounded in single quotes. (See also both below answers for the same thoughts expressed as full code rewrites instead of English diffs like I've presented. :))

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald you're absolutely right, typo on my part. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, Kyle. Don't forget to add the `print` statement as well!

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

awk '{
  if ( $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) {
    $1 = "chr"$1
  } else  {
    $1 = "chrUn_"$1
  }
  print
}' bio.txt
```

Comment: extra `*` in regex

Comment: Beware that assigning to a single field e.g. `$1` will cause awk to reformat the whole line, inserting the `OFS` between each field.

Comment: @TomFenech: can you elaborate? I noticed that the formatting subtly changed after running the above script: what was a tab-delimited file became a space-delimited file. Is that what the `OFS` insertion refers to? Forgive me if that's a stupid question, I'm still new to the command line.

Answer (score 2):

your regex is not right

```
$ awk           '{pre="UNKNOWN"} 
    $1~/^[0-9]+$/{pre="chr"} 
         $1~/^KN/{pre="chrUn_"} {print pre $0}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for something like this:

```
awk '{ print "chr" ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ? "" : "Un_") $0 }' file
```

You have problems with quotes in your attempt; you can't use single quotes inside a single-quoted string (and in this case, you shouldn't try to).

I've used a conditional operator to print either string, avoiding the need for `if`/`else`.

Testing with your sample input:

```
$ awk '{ print "chr" ($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/ ? "" : "Un_") $0 }' file
chr1 100 100
chr1 100 100
chrUn_KN1234 100 100
```

This method preserves the original structure of the line. Beware when assigning to individual fields e.g. changing `$1` to something else, as this will cause awk to reformat the whole line, inserting the Output Field Separator `OFS` (a single space by default) between each field . A typical consequence of this is that multiple spaces between fields are lost.

Comment: This works perfectly as well, and is probably a clearer solution given what I'm trying to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just prepend everything with `chr` and if there is a `KN` add the `Un_`:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^/,"chr") && sub(/^chrKN/,"chrUn_KN") || 1' foo
chr1 100 100
chr1 100 100
chrUn_KN1234 100 100
```